# Extracting JavaScript function return value using Python Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am scraping information from a webpage. The following is a snippet of the Javascript function that I am looking to extract the return string value from. In this case `"2227885"`

[image]

I have used the following method from selenium to attempt to extract this value:

```
result = driver.execute_script("getCurrentClientId()[0]")
print(result)
```

However, the value returned is `None`. What is the proper solution to extract the return value from this JS function?

Answer (score 1):

use "return" as part of your javascript:

```
result = driver.execute_script("return getCurrentClientId()[0]")
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = driver.execute_script("return getCurrentClientId()")
print(result)
```

if the function is not within the html source ,and you want to pass explicitly then use

```
result = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0]", getCurrentClientId)
print(result)
```

what ever we pass to execute_script will be passed into arguments arraay in the same order. so the getCurrentClientId can be accessed in the script as arguments[0]